# Redirect all traffic from URL1 to URL2 except certain directory

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8

What I need to do is redirect all traffic from URL1 to URL2 unless the request URI is /certain-directory. Along with that I'd need to redirect anything that's URL1/certain-directory to URL2/certain directory.

Here are the 2 rules I've come up with that I'm troubleshooting.

```
    <rule name="Redirect to certain-directory" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/certain-directory$" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^URL1$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://URL2/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect from certain-directory" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/certain-directory$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^URL2$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://URL1/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just had the ending to the request_uri's wrong. Instead of

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/certain-directory$" negate="true" />
```

I just needed

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/certain-directory" negate="true" />
```